# Como pegar o thumbnail WordPress com PHP puro?

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de pegar a URL dos thumbnails no banco de dados do WordPress usando PHP puro para colocar em um projeto Magento afim de mostrar os posts na página inicial.

Como essa relação **Magento -> Wordpress** é um pouco complicada, gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a pegar a `Featured Image` de cada post para inserir na página inicial do ecommerce.

O que eu já fiz:

```
function SimpleLoopWordpress (){

    try {

        // PDO em ação!
        $pdo = new PDO ( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=", "", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date ASC";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $i = 1;
        echo '<div class="row">';

        while ( $linha = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) {

            ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <?php 
                         echo $i++;
                         echo FEATURED IMAGE <--------
                         echo $linha->post_title;
                         echo $linha->post_date;
                         echo $linha->post_content;
                    ?>  
                </div>

            <?php

        }

        echo '</div>';

    }
```

Provavelmente vou pegar esta imagem aqui:

[image: attachment no banco de dados]

Comment: Recomendo que além de imagem, poste os dados de verdade, nem sempre é facil testar dados que estão em fotos. Eu chutei uma resposta, pode haver falhas, mas o caminho é este.

Comment: Tem o XMLRPC ou então com o plugin semi-oficial da API JSON, mas não são PHP puro.. Se o título fosse "pegar o thumb externamente (fora do wp)", podia responder, senão seria uma resposta fora do escopo do que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este `metavalue` parece ser uma variável "serializada" com http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Então bastaria usar o [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Ficaria algo como:

```
    while ( $linha = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) {

        ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php
                     //Verifica se o campo é vazio ou nulo e então converte
                     $meta_value = empty($linha->meta_value) ? NULL : unserialize($linha->meta_value);

                     //Resultado da conversão
                     var_dump($meta_value);

                     //Pega o nome da imagem
                     $imagem_url = $meta_value ? $meta_value['file'] : NULL;

                     echo $i++;
                     echo $imagem_url ? $imagem_url : 'Sem foto';
                     echo $linha->post_title;
                     echo $linha->post_date;
                     echo $linha->post_content;
                ?>  
            </div>

        <?php

    }
```

Eu não tenho certeza do que o [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) vai retornar, pois você postou uma imagem do `meta_value` e não tenho como reproduzir o valor, mas acredito ser isto, o `var_dump` deve lhe ajudar a detectar as chaves corretas do `meta_value`.